# API is working but I can't get axios to write out the data being returned from the API

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm hitting an API using Axios that looks like this when I connect to it via the browser (https://localhost:41216/api/articles):

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Detection of solar neutron events and their theoretical approach","groupById":2,"groupBy":null},
{"id":2,"name":"Dark energy and modified scale covariant theory of gravitation","groupById":2,"groupBy":null},
{"id":3,"name":"United theory of planet formation (i): Tandem regime","groupById":2,"groupBy":null}]
```

I had it working but it was hard-coded like this:

```
import React from "react";

const OptionList = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <option value='Article' label='Select an article' />
            <option value='1' label='Detection of solar neutron events and their theoretical approach' />
            <option value='2' label='Dark energy and modified scale covariant theory of gravitation' />
            <option value='3' label='United theory of planet formation (i): Tandem regime' />               
        </>
    )
}

export default OptionList;
```

But I want to use the API, so I started coding this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const OptionList = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'https://localhost:41216/api/articles',
            );
            setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {data.map(item => (
                <option value={item.id} label={item.name} />
            ))}
        </>

    );
}
export default OptionList;
```

But I keep getting an error that says

```
TypeError: data.map is not a function
```

I know the API is working, because I visit the URL in my browser, I get returned data like the example I put above.

Comment: data is initially a *string*, which doesn't have a map method. Either provide an array as the default, or handle the initial case explicitly (probably with null or undefined rather than an empty string).

Answer (score 1):

This

```
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
```

initializes `data`'s default value as an empty string.

simply,

```
    const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
```

Fixes the issue by initializing data as an empty array to have a `.map` method.

I would also

```
    function renderOptions() {
        if(data.length <= 0) {
            return <Loader />
        }
        return data.map(item => (
            <option value={item.id} label={item.name} />
        ))
    }

    return (
        <>
            {renderOptions()}
        </>

    );
```

This can show a loader screen while your `data` has nothing to map and generate `<option>`s.

Comment: Thanks, would the function 'renderOptions' go inside my 'const OptionList = () => {'?

Comment: Yeah! Everything I wrote goes inside the `OptionList` component otherwise you would want to use `data` as a parameter in `renderOptions` and call `{renderOptions(data)}` inside the `OptionsList` component.